# Difference between Send Priority and Message Priority

Tags: marketing-cloud

I’m struggling to understand the difference between ‘Send Priority’ in Send Classifications within Email Studio Setup and ‘Message Priority’ within Advanced Options in Journey Builder.

I’ve looked up resources, and I understand the differences between classifications but I’m still confused on what makes these two different (or the same!).